# Read performance of RAID4

Tags: raid

In [the Wikipedia article for RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels), there is a chart which shows read performance of various RAID levels, and it claims that RAID4 has a read performance factor of `1-(1-r)^n -nr(1-r)^(n-1)` while RAID5 has a read performance of `n`. For a single stripe, it seems like RAID5 would have read performance factor of `n-1`, however I see that for larger sets of data it would benefit from reading the additional drive to the point where the factor would be close to `n`. That said, I have no idea what the `r` in the RAID4 factor refers to.

Why isn't the RAID4 read performance factor simply `n-1`?

Comment: Did you happen to notice [citation needed] ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. r is undefined, that looks like a copy paste error or confused editor.

Your intuition is probably right in that reads are about n-1 disks.

In practice, RAID 4 does not matter. "Standard" RAID levels for most use cases should be limited to 1, 10, and 6.